censusxy::cxy_geocode() not recognizing variable names
I am trying to use the censusxy package to geocode a few addresses.  The cxy_geocode() function has worked before, but it now doesn't seem to recognize variable names.
For example, suppose I have the data.frame below.
sites <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~street_address,                ~city,         ~state,     ~zipcode,
    '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW',  'Washington',  'DC',       20500
  )


For some reason, this doesn't work.
library(tidyverse)
library(censusxy)

# this doesn't work
sites %>% 
  cxy_geocode(
    street = street_address,
    city = city,
    state = state,
    zip = zipcode
  )
#> Error in cxy_geocode(., street = street_address, city = city, state = state, : object 'city' not found

But this does.
# but this does?
sites %>% 
  transmute(
    full_address = str_glue('{street_address}, {city}, {state} {zipcode}')
  ) %>% 
  pull() %>% 
  cxy_oneline()
#>   tigerLine.side tigerLine.tigerLineId coordinates.x coordinates.y
#> 1              L              76225813     -77.03654      38.89869
#>   addressComponents.zip addressComponents.streetName addressComponents.preType
#> 1                 20500                 PENNSYLVANIA                          
#>   addressComponents.city addressComponents.preDirection
#> 1             WASHINGTON                               
#>   addressComponents.suffixDirection addressComponents.fromAddress
#> 1                                NW                          1500
#>   addressComponents.state addressComponents.suffixType
#> 1                      DC                          AVE
#>   addressComponents.toAddress addressComponents.suffixQualifier
#> 1                        1698                                  
#>   addressComponents.preQualifier
#> 1                               
#>                                    matchedAddress
#> 1 1600 PENNSYLVANIA AVE NW, WASHINGTON, DC, 20500

Created on 2024-05-01 with reprex v2.0.2

The arguments of cxy_geocode() expect strings as input. Just wrap all your column names in quotation marks (e.g., city = "city"). That worked for me. Also, per request of the maintainer, censusxy is no longer on CRAN. I would recommend migrating over to the tidygeocoder package, which uses the US Census geocoder but also many others, such as Google, Bing, OSM Nominatim, Mapbox, etc.
